# iOS 13 UIView transform3D

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewanimation, ios13

In iOS 13, UIView exposes the `transform3D` property. Evidently it is the layer's `transform` property. It is animatable! So now we can do cool CATransform3D transforms and animations directly on the view instead of having to drop down to the level of the layer.

The availability attribute seems to claim that this is available in iOS 12 as well:

```
@available(iOS 12.0, *)
```

But if you use this property under iOS 12, your code compiles because of the availability attribute, but crashes because the availability attribute seems to be lying (unrecognized selector). Is the availability attribute a bug?

Also, can anyone shed light on the purpose of this property's exposure? I realize that it's just nice to be able to include 3D transforms in your view animations, but usually this sort of change happens because Apple needs to expose the property to some other API. My guess is that they did this because the SwiftUI people wanted it for their `rotation3DEffect` modifier...?

Comment: Hey Matt, did you ever learn more about this? Whatever changes Apple made to the Core Animation framework around the `CATransform3D` struct, it has affected some of the results of my transformations. The exact same transformations seem to behave slightly differently in iOS 13 than they did in iOS 12 when using the `UIView.animate` methods to animate them.

I'd appreciate any light you could bring to the subject. Thanks.

Comment: @GarretKaye Really??? Could you give an example? Ask a new question about this and blip me with a link. Thanks.

Comment: will do. I'll clip a video together so it's easy to see exactly whats going on and  post the question. Thanks again

Comment: Hey Matt, here's the link to the post I created - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58514193/ios-13-catransform3d-issues